# How to implement custom membership provider on Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I want to implement custom membership provider in my project and I'm using repository pattern in my application.

**Here is my project structure: (3 projects)**

- MyProject (Asp.Net MVC)
- MyProject.Model (Entity model classes. I'm using entity framework)
- MyProject.Repository (My repository classes)

Where do I implement the custom membership class? Since it's inherit from System.Web.Security; I should create in MyProject?

What is the right way to create custom membership class with Repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create one more project `MyProject.Infrastructure` that will contain your custom membership classes and other core components related to your application infrastructure.

You have to register the custom membership class through web.config so it's difficult for you inject the dependencies like your database repository to the class and so there is no much gain in implementing a repository pattern in your custom membership provider class. Anyway you have to instantiate a concrete repository implementation inside the membership class.

Comment: Reason I choose the repository pattern is to separate the core logic from the UI. I want to have the flexibility to create windows 8 app or windows phone app with the same code, replacing the UI. Do you think I should create a WCF custom membership service?